# NodeJS get session variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, server

im doing a Stripe Identity Verification and im close to the end.
I wanted, that after a successfull verification, it gets the the id from the user through the session, which i declared in PHP in an other file and sets *verified = 1* in my MySQL Database. The problem is, that i have no idea how to get a session variable through NodeJS.
Can somebody help?

(btw, the code + nodejs is in a linux server)

Comment: Are you trying to share the same session in PHP and nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should look at the documentation here:https://stripe.com/docs/identity/verify-identity-documents

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

// In the route handler for /create-verification-session:
// Authenticate your user.

// Create the session.
const verificationSession = await stripe.identity.verificationSessions.create({
  type: 'document',
  metadata: {
    user_id: '{{USER_ID}}',
  },
});

// Create an ephemeral key for the VerificationSession
const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  {verification_session: verificationSession.id},
  {apiVersion: '2022-08-01'}
);

// Return only the ID and ephemeral key secret to the frontend.
const verficationSessionId = verificationSession.id;
const ephemeralKeySecret = ephemeralKey.secret;
```